# Get a stream of video from gstreamer to a directshow pipeline?

Tags: c++, directshow, gstreamer

I would like to render a video stream from a gstreamer pipeline into a directshow one. I was wondering if I had to write a directshow filter source getting data from the pipeline or if it was simpler? If I have to, I don't really see where I could get an idea of what to do.

Comment: Unless GStreamer provides its own source filter (which is something I am not aware of), you have to provide your own filter. `PushSource` SDK sample is the closest start point.